# How to implement pipe in a input type while using Angular2?

Tags: angular

I am new to angularJS2 and I am trying to implement pipe in the input type text of a form. For instance if I have a input tag like this

```
  <input type="text" class="col-lg-7 small rounded form-control" formControlName="firstName" />
```

I want the value entered in the text field to be all uppercase, can we achieve this inside a input element of a form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to use pipes on inputs.

You can however run your pipe within an input method.

```
this.toUpper = new UpperCasePipe().transform(input);
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 4):

1 - You can't use pipes on **inputs**. To achieve this kind of thing you could use `(keyup)` *event*:

```
<input 
  type="text"
  class="col-lg-7 small rounded form-control" 
  formControlName="firstName" 
  (keyup)="upperValue($event.target.value)">
```

**Component:**

```
upperValue(value: string) {
  this.formGroup.patchValue({
    firstName: value.toUpperCase() 
  });
}
```

<kbd>[**STACKBLITZ DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-qpkx2s)</kbd>

---

2 - If you want to show the **original** text for user and modify it "behind the scenes", you can create a directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appUppercase]'
})
export class UppercaseDirective implements OnInit {

  private readonly destroySubject$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(
    private readonly ngControl: NgControl
  ) { }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroySubject$.next();
    this.destroySubject$.complete();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ngControl.control.valueChanges.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroySubject$)
    ).subscribe(value => {
      const newValue = value.toUpperCase();

      this.ngControl.control.setValue(newValue, {
        emitEvent: false,
        emitModelToViewChange: false,
        emitViewToModelChange: false
      });
    });
  }
}
```

<kbd>[**STACKBLITZ DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-cpjbbb)</kbd>

---

3 - If you want to display the *modified* text for user and maintain it lowercased in `formControl`, modify the following lines in directive:

```
...
this.elementRef.nativeElement.value = value.toUpperCase();

this.ngControl.control.setValue(value.toLowerCase(), {
  emitEvent: false,
  emitModelToViewChange: false,
  emitViewToModelChange: false
});
...
```

<kbd>[**STACKBLITZ DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-gppvgk)</kbd>

Comment: But, what if I want to use the uppercase only on presentation layer?
So the formControlvalue will be as the user typed.. with out any formatting

Comment: @developer033 - what does emitViewToModelChange: false do in your example, can't find any difference between true or false values for this property