# How to apply pipe on formcontrolname in angular 2

Tags: angular, input, pipe

I have an input type text which displays value using formControlName. I have written a Pipe to format the value.
How can I apply this pipe(testpipe) on formControlName. I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42249431/how-to-implement-pipe-in-a-input-type-while-using-angular2?rq=1) that you cannot apply pipe directly on input type text.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'testPipe' })
export class TestPipe implements PipeTransform {
public transform(value: string): string {
   //some logic
    return value;

  }
}
```

How can I apply this pipe

```
<input tabindex="1" type="text" class="form-control-style" 
formControlName="abc" id="abc" name="abc" 
readonly >
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the pipe using the double curly brace notation. Like so:

```html
<input tabindex="1" type="text" class="form-control-style" 
  formControlName="{{'abc' | testPipe}}" id="abc" name="abc" readonly >
```

## [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjtjrb)

Comment: I added a demo for you to see it in action.

Comment: This doesn't work, and you did not use `name1` for formControlName [Demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjtjrb) @TeddySterne

Comment: @Chenna the demo works for me. I see three form input that are bound based on the prefix `name` and the suffix either `1`, `2`, or `3` based on the value from the `ngFor`.

Comment: That is not a suitable solution. It can be done without pipes. Like that " formControlName="{{ 'abc' + index }}" "

Answer (score 1):

thats works great on angular 8 , for form group formControlName with pipe:

short:

```
      [value]="form.get('my_form_group_field').value | MyPipe"
```

longer:

```
      <input
       [readonly]="isEditMode"
       formControlName="my_form_group_field" 
       matInput
       type="text"
       [value]="form.get('my_form_group_field').value | MyPipe"
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a "template expression". From Angular documentation:

> A template expression produces a value. Angular executes the
>   expression and assigns it to a property of a binding target; the
>   target might be an HTML element, a component, or a directive.
>
> The interpolation braces in `{{1 + 1}}` surround the template expression
>   `1 + 1`.

In your case, build a template expression applying your custom pipe:

```
<input tabindex="1" type="text" class="form-control-style" formControlName="{{'abc' | testPipe}}" id="abc" name="abc" readonly >
```

Comment: I think I know why it is not working, when my form is loaded I don't have a value set for that text input. Only after some action, the value gets set. How can we stop this pipe being executed without value. I tried to check for undefined ,still breaks

Comment: The pipe is applying on the formControlName, not on the input text value, so I think it's not related with it. You should have a valid formControlName value at any time, it can't be null, undifined or refer to some fomControl that not exists. Can you show more detail about the error or more code maybe? Thanks!

Comment: Assuming I changed to this formControlName="{{'abc' | testPipe}}" and when I put console.log in the transform method, it just executes once when the form is loaded, when the text input gets some value when a btn is clicked, I don't see transform getting called

Answer (score 0):

You can transform an input value with [value]="form.controls.abc.value | testPipe"

This works well with readonly fields that you want to display in an input field.

You can still use formControlName="abc" with some success, depending on how your pipe modifies the value in abc.

Answer (score 0):

Use value attribute to set the data along with corresponding pipe

```
<input type="text" matInput placeholder="Created Date" 
formControlName="createdDate" 
[value]="myForm.get('createdDate').value | date">
```